# RegSvcs Error - System.IO.FileNotFoundException - Could not load file or assembly

Tags: com

I want to register COM+ Application using RegSvcs. A error occurs:

An unknown exception occurred during installation:
  1: System.IO.FileNotFoundException - Could not load file or assembly 'ServiceSta
  ck.Redis, Version=3.9.32.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=63fa1090bba1cba5' or
  one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

There are 6 dependent dlls in the project and 2 among them are 3rd dlls which i put into the speical folder. And other dlls are from: 
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ and 
  C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5.

If anyone encouter this issue before, pls reply to me. Thanks.

Comment: Should i replace the dlls from. why you dont try? if not work ask again

Comment: i have tried but failed.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, open the Solution Explorer window and expand the References node. Right-click the reference to your assemblies and click Properties. In the properties window change the Copy Local as True, it will copy the assembly to the output folder of the project ('bin\Debug' or 'bin\Release').

Comment: finally i figure it out. the 3rd dlls runtime version is different from RegSvcs.exe.